# Two partial classes into two files that one is sub item of the other and can be expanded

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, partial-classes

I added two partial classes that have the same name:

```
public partial class SomePartial
{
}
```

and now I have two separate files.

I want to make them appear as single item in the project, that can be expanded like in a WebForms project where you have the `Form.cs` and you have the `Form.Designer.cs`.

Comment: The question title is a bit unfortunate, because you don't really want them in the same file, you just want one file to be shown as a sub-item of the other (if I understand you correctly). The confusion is probably why the question was downvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by editing the .csproj-file by hand.

Right-click the project and select "Unload project", then right-click it again and choose "Edit .csproj".

This is an .xml file which describes your project and its dependencies. You need to find the entries that describe the files of your partial class, e.g.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MyPartialClass.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MyPartialClass.Extension.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now you can set one as a sub-item of the other by adding a `DependendUpon` subtag:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MyPartialClass.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MyPartialClass.Extension.cs">
        <DependentUpon>MyPartialClass.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Save the file, and re-load the project.

Comment: Visual Studio can also do this automatically based on naming convention. If you create two files, `Foo.cs` and `Foo.designer.cs` it would nest them automatically. If you want something other than `designer` however, this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have much sense to have a partial class in the same file, IMHO. The main goal of partial classes is to allow more that one person to work with the same class, and if someone checks out this file from your code repo, this facility is gone.
Other goal is to keep manual code away from auto-generated code so it don't get lost when regeneration happens.
That said, you coul use code region to achive what you want.

```
#region Partial 1
// Code here
#endregion 

#region Partial 2
// Code here
#endregion
```

Comment: The question isn't worded very well, but I don't think this is what OP meant.

Comment: I changed the name of the question my mistake

Answer (score 0):

In `dotnet core`, you might get error `NETSDK1022` when added `Compile` items into `csproj`.

To solve the issue, the source files must be removed first then add later, for example.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="MyPartialClass.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="MyPartialClass.Extension.cs"/>

    <Compile Include="MyPartialClass.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MyPartialClass.Extension.cs">
        <DependentUpon>MyPartialClass.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

The error `NETSDK1022` shows because in `dotnet core` all source files inside project directory are included to compile by default then try to add `Compile` item cause duplicated source files. But in `.Net Framework` didn't throw error because all source files must be explicitly listed/included in `csproj`.